# Element On Pop-Up Window Not Found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to find the elements of a log-in mask on [mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/). Waiting for an element to be visible using the following code

```
public WebElement waitForElement(By identifier)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOfElementLocated(identifier));
}
```

times out even though the element is there after about 1 second.

I tried to locate the e-mail field using `By.xPath("//*[@id=\"widget_login_email\"]")` and `By.cssSelector("#widget_login_email")` but neither worked.

`driver.getWindowHandles().size()` returns `1` so there's no other window which needs to be switched to.

This is the html:

```
<form id="form_login1" method="post" action="/dynamic/client_login/mediafire.php" target="widgetwork"> <label class="ieLabel">Email address</label> <input type="email" pattern="^(.)+@[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9\.-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.[A-Za-z]{1,13}$" name="login_email" id="widget_login_email" placeholder="Email address"> <label class="ieLabel">Password</label> <input type="password" name="login_pass" id="widget_login_pass" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30"> <div id="login_remember_wrap"><input type="checkbox" name="login_remember" id="login_remember" checked="checked"><label for="login_remember">Keep me logged in</label></div> <a class="forgotPassword" href="/lost_password.php" target="_blank">Forgot password?</a> <button type="submit" class="gbtnTertiary" onclick="">Log in</button> </form>
```

Please help me to find those elements using WebDriver.

Note:
I'm using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, I assume, is you are getting a `NoSuchElementException`.

The reason for your issue is the element is contained within an `iframe`.  Specifically, this one:

```
<iframe name="modal_msg_iframe" id="modal_msg_iframe" src="/templates/login_signup/login_signup.php?dc=loginPath&amp;_svefr=2390" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 686px; height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

You will need to switch to that `iframe` before you can access the element.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("modal_msg_iframe");
```

Comment: Exactly, it works now. I must've missed that iframe.